# Assignment between non-primitive variables by value in Java

Tags: java, list, variable-assignment

```
private List<CourseGroupBean> courseGroups = new ArrayList<CourseGroupBean>();
...
courseGroups = getAlgorithmUtil().listCourses();
...
List<CourseGroupBean> courseGroupsTwo = courseGroups;
```

I know that if I do the third line it will assing the reference of courseGroups to courseGroupsTwo but I want to assign just the values of it. How to do that in Java?

**EDIT**

I mean, when I remove/add an object at courseGroupsTwo it musn't change anything at courseGroups.

Comment: Are you saying you want to make a copy of the object and not the reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't natively support copy-by-value for Objects, so you have to do it yourself:

```
List<CourseGroupBean> courseGroupsTwo = new ArrayList<CourseGroupBean>(courseGroups);
```

will perform a shallow copy of `courseGroups`, i.e. it will create a new list that contains the same objects as `courseGroups`. You can replace `ArrayList` with a more appropriate `List` implementation if required.

You can also use `clone` if you like. `clone` is a bit nasty because you need to do a cast after the clone. Casting is generally bad because it possibly introduces run-time errors, whereas the code above will generate compile-time errors if something is wrong.

Comment: Also, if both lists already exist, you can use `java.util.Collections.copy(courseGroupsTwo, courseGroups)`

Comment: According to your answer, when I remove an element from courseGroupsTwo, does it cause a change at courseGroups?

Comment: No. `courseGroupsTwo` and `courseGroups` are different objects, but they contain shared references to the original `CourseGroupBean` objects. Removing a reference from `courseGroupsTwo` will not affect the reference in `courseGroups`.

Comment: Can you explain this: "Casting is generally bad because it possibly introduces run-time errors, whereas the code above will generate compile-time errors if something is wrong." Because I get some strange errors at my code.

Comment: If you use a cast then you might get a `ClassCastException` at run-time. Run-time errors are sometimes hide to debug because they may depend on user input or other hard-to-reproduce details. Compile-time errors are much easier to debug because they are always reproducible and the compiler will often be able to give a specific error message that tells you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a 'deep copy' of the list.  See this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303098/how-to-backup-arraylist-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

```
     List<CourseGroupBean> courseGroupsTwo = (ArrayList<CourseGroupsBean>) courseGroups.clone();
```

But there is more than just calling .clone().  According to this resource below, your class also must implement the interface Cloneable; otherwise, a CloneNotSupportedException is thrown:

http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/clone-method-example-in-java.shtml

Comment: `CloneNotSupportedException` is not a problem in this case because `ArrayList` implements cloneable and `clone` does a shallow copy so the `CourseGroupsBean` objects won't be cloned.

Answer (score 0):

Call constructor `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E>)`:

```
List<CourseGroupBean> courseGroupsTwo = new ArrayList<CourseGroupBean>(courseGroups)
```